# What is the difference between Kubernetes and Amazon ECS

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices, amazon-ecs

What is the difference between Amazon ECS and Kubernetes implementation architecture?

I need to decide to pick a technology for container management in cloud.
What is the deciding factor while picking any of these technology?

I am using Docker for container creation and execution.

Comment: Amazon ECS is not open source so one can only speculate about its architectural design decisions. The deciding factor should be what you value, and the features each of those backends prioritize. A detailed discussion of pros/cons is not befitting of a stack overflow answer. If you want to start off on bare metal and gradullay move to the cloud (gke/gce/aws) I suggest Kubernetes, simply because you can play with it on localhost/vagrant before paying.

Comment: As a follow up suggestion, you should get on slack (kubernetes.slack.com) or on a mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/kubernetes-dev or https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-containers) with questions you might have about individual features.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had a huge experience working with containers and different container solutions, including Amazon ECS and Kubernetes, and I have found, that Kubernetes as one of the most useful solutions for managing containers in the different environments.

The main benefit of Kubernetes - that it is a mature solution, originally developed by Google, but it is completely open-source! That means that anyone may look under the hood and (if necessary), modify and update the source code up to his purposes.

Another huge benefit of Kubernetes - it is completely free. That mean that you may install it and run on your own infrastructure, without paying any additional costs for Kubernetes itself.

You may run Kubernetes on the huge amount of [different providers](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/README.html). It doesn't matter on what environment do you run the Kubernetes cluster - you should only take care of the Kubernetes cluster itself. That allows you to run, for example, the development cluster locally on Vagrant, as make the distributed production environment on the public cloud like AWS or GCE and the private cloud like OpenStack or simply using some libvirt solutions (using CoreOS for example). Again, from the point of view of Kubernetes - it doesn't matter what infrastructure solution do you use - the only one requirement for it - to be Kubernetes-enabled.

Speaking about the Amazon ECS - that is a proprietary and vendor-locked solution. It also may give you the same performance as Kubernetes, but it won't give you the same flexibility.

So, globally one may compare both Amazon ECS and Kubernetes, but Kubernetes is much more flexible and ready-to-customize solution.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sorry, your question makes no sense. It's like asking

> What is better? A rental car or a Ford?

AWS provides IaaS, Kubernetes is system to manage distributed containers. You can run Kubernetes on various platforms, *including* AWS-provided infrastructure.

Do you want to pay Amazon to host your Docker containers? [You can do that](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/).

Or do you want to create your own "cloud" where you run your Docker containers? Then get yourself some bare metal and use (for example) [CoreOS](https://coreos.com/) and [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/gettingstarted/) on top.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, i rectified my question. my actual question is difference between kubernetes and Amazon ECS.